# Stop .animate() when if statement is true

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery game though I can't make the character stop when it hits the edge of the `div` in which the game is held.

Is there a way that once the `.animate()` has started it stops when the margin-left is a certain amount?

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qUufA/5/

Comment: look at step callback function

Comment: What does that mean, sorry I'm not that good at JQuery.

Comment: Can you give a demo or some code to check out how you've accomplished some of the tasks?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm) helps...

Comment: You may wish to look into a different method of moving the character. And rather than using a div, consider using the HTML5 canvas. The animate method is not ideal for this.

Comment: I know that it is not ideal though I haven't got a clue of any other way of moving my character though will try using a canvas

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ipolew/1/edit)**</kbd>

Instead of **animate**, run an **Interval**, check for **collisions** and do your **moves**.
Store all **keys** into an object `m` (moves) :

```
var c = $(".character");
var g = $(".game");
var m = {}; // moves
var intv;
var coll = {}; // collisions
var e1, e2;

$(document).on('keydown keyup',function ( e ) {
  var keyDown = e.type == "keydown"; 
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      m.left = keyDown;
      break;
    case 38:
      m.up = keyDown;
      break;
    case 39:
      m.right = keyDown;
      break;
    case 40:
      m.down = keyDown;
      break;
  } 
});

function collisions( el1, el2 ){
  e1 = {
    W : el1.width(),
    H : el1.height()
  };
  e2 = {
    X : el2.position().left,
    Y : el2.position().top,
    W : el2.width(),
    H : el2.height()
  };  
  coll.left   = e2.X <= 0 ;
  coll.up    = e2.Y <= 0 ;  
  coll.right  = e2.X+e2.W >= e1.W ; 
  coll.down = e2.Y+e2.H >= e1.H ;
}

function movePX(){
    collisions( g, c );
    if (m.left ) {
      c.css({left: coll.left ? 0 : "-=2"});
    }
    if (m.up) {
      c.css({top: coll.up ? 0 : "-=2"});
    }
    if (m.right) {
      c.css({ left: coll.right ? e1.W-e2.W : "+=2" });
    }
    if (m.down) {
      c.css({top: coll.down ? e1.H-e2.H : "+=2"});
    }
}

// Engine
intv = setInterval(function() {
   movePX();
   // put other functions here
}, 10);
```

Comment: The separation between Engine and the other logic is really nice

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use step callback function and see if it can help you.
**step** callback function takes two parameters, **now** and **fx**.
**fx** object has all the properties of element which you can use it in your gaming app.

For your purpose you can use **fx.elem.offsetLeft** property.

e.g.

```
$('li').animate({
  opacity: .5,
  height: '50%'
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
    console.log(fx.elem.offsetLeft); //gives you the margin left of current element
  }
});
```

To know more refer : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

This is sample workout.

```
var c = $(".character");
var g = $(".game");
var _anim = false; // global variable 

function get_margin(sel, pos) {
     return parseInt(sel.css('margin-' + pos).replace('px'), 10);
}

// only for left arrow
// I hope u can do the rest

    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
         if ( get_margin(c, 'left') ===  50) {
                _anim.stop();
         } else {
                _anim = $('.character').animate({
                         'margin-left': '-=20px'
                       });
         }
    }
```

**[Partially done JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qUufA/7/)**